# Setting up Ionic 2 Cordova Camera Plugin

Tags: typescript, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2

```
 initializeApp(){
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       {
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      }

   function onDeviceReady() {
       console.log(navigator.camera);
       console.log("Cordova");
      }

 }
```

We are trying to run the onDeviceReady function and console.log will not print out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 initializeApp(){
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
         console.log(navigator.camera);
         console.log("Cordova");
     }
 }
```

`Platform.ready()` resolves when `deviceready` has fired, so listening for it again is unnecessary.  In this case, listening for it after it has fired will cause that handler to never execute.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are running into a race condition where `deviceready` is firing before `platform.ready`.

My recommendation is to handle both cases where `deviceready` fires before `platform.ready` and the reverse as well. To do that you should follow this pattern.

Somewhere outside of the angular world, so probably in your startup js file.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", () => window['isCordovaReady'] = true, false);
```

Then you can use this in in your `initializeApp` method

```
initializeApp(){
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    if(!!window['isCordovaReady']){
      onDeviceReady();
    } else {        
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
      console.log(navigator.camera);
      console.log("Cordova");
    }
  }
}
```

Also you have a syntax error in your code that you posted.

```
initializeApp(){
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    { <-- This is extra and should be removed.
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    } <-- Missing a ');'

  function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(navigator.camera);
    console.log("Cordova");
  }
 }
```